# WKWebView detect links like UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, wkwebview

UIWebView has options to detect links, phone numbers, events, and addresses.  How can we turn that on for a WKWebView?

Comment: I dont think wkwebview has an option to set the data detector types. You should probably handle that yourself by checking the url scheme